# Nullable object must have a value Error after converting query from SQL Server view to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to covert the following query from SQL to LINQ but I cannot achieve the same result as query execution on SQL Server. The query is the following one

```
SELECT * 
FROM T_Students AS s
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         dbo.T_Students.ID_Student, 
         MAX(f_no_marker.Date) AS RecentDate
     FROM 
         dbo.T_Students 
     INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_Exam ON dbo.T_Students.ID_Student = dbo.T_Exam.ID_Student 
     INNER JOIN
          (SELECT        
               ID_Exam, ID_Multi, Date
           FROM          
               dbo.T_File
           WHERE        
               (ID_Type <> 12) AND ([Primary] = 1)) AS f_no_marker ON dbo.T_Exam.ID_Multi = f_no_marker.ID_Multi
     GROUP BY 
         dbo.T_Students.ID_Student) AS m_date ON s.ID_Student = m_date.ID_Student
ORDER BY
    RecentDate
```

The relation between the three tables are Students->Exams->Files.

I write the following code but I think that there are something wrong

```
var filesWithLastExamDate = from f in sourceContext.ExamFiles
     where f.ExamFileType.Type != strPatMkr
             && f.Primary == true
             && f.UsedByResource == resource.Description
             group f by new { FileId = f.ID, ExamId = f.ExamID } into g
             select new { FileId = g.Key, RecentDate = g.Max(d => d.Date) };

var examsWithFiles = from e in sourceContext.Exams
    join f in filesWithLastExamDate on e.ID equals f.FileId.ExamId into eef
    from ef in eef
    select new
    {
      ef.FileId.ExamId,
      ef.RecentDate
    };

var studentsWithLastExamDate = from s in sourceContext.Student
   join eef in examsWithFiles on s equals eef.ExamId into pef
   from ple in pef.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new { StudentId = s, ple.RecentDate };
```

When I call `studentsWithLastExamDate.ToList()`, I get the following error

> Nullable object must have a value

The expected result is to have students sorted with both null value and not null value.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does your `ple.RecentDate` has any null values ?

Comment: Start from simple answer, which ORM do you use?

Comment: RecentDate has null values because a student should have no exams but I want to see also students that not have an exam.

Comment: EF core 7 is the version actually in use

Answer (score 0):

> RecentDate has null values because a student should have no exams but
> I want to see also students that not have an exam.
> The expected result is to have students sorted with both null value and not null
> value.

Based on the above input; we can check whether ple is null before accessing its `RecentDate` property using null-conditional operator `?`.

```
var studentsWithLastExamDate = from s in sourceContext.Student
   join eef in examsWithFiles on s.ID equals eef.ExamId into pef
   from ple in pef.DefaultIfEmpty()
   orderby ple != null ? ple.RecentDate : null
   select new { StudentId = s.ID, RecentDate = ple?.RecentDate };

var result = studentsWithLastExamDate.ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but now the error is  `An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator`.  RecentDate is not a nullable object.

Comment: I have updated answer; Can you please check it ?

Comment: The first solution works, but trying converting the query from SQL to LINQ I made a big mistake on Max calulation.
Can @thusar give me a review of LINQ starting from SQL query?

Comment: @RiccardoZamuner I have updated the answer;
Can you please let me know if you face any problems ? If it do not work; you can keep your previous approach as I am not a Linq expert :)

Comment: I've tested your solution but when I try to call studentsWithMaxDate I've got an SqlException 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

Comment: sorry for late answer but the implementation of the feature related to the posted query was postponed. We re-arrenge our entities on database and the whole query was totally reviewed. Thanks anyway for your support

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't keep track of post and couldn't help you further.